# How can I access the MySQL command line with xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm trying to access to MYSQL from xampp using this command:

```
mysql.exe -u root --password
```

There's not any problem with that. But, because of I have two Mysql in my PC (One of them is independent (its port is 3306), and the another one was installed with xampp (port 3307)). The problem is because when I access to Mysql from xampp's folder and then I verify the port, it says that the port is 3306, not 3307.

I'm doing all of this because I need to know the mysql's version in xampp.

So I would like to know how to access to mysql in xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I'm doing all of this because I need to know the mysql's version in xampp.`

What about

```
SELECT VERSION()
```

It's all you need to get version.

Comment: That works perfectly. I think I complicated it more than necessary. Thank you so much.